# How can I query 2 different "WHERE" from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
151 - Transaction table for Received
202 - Transaction table for Put-away

hu_ID - Carton 
Employee_ID - Employee Name
Control_number_2 - PO#
Location_ID_2 - Location
```

FYI Dates will be present

**In short I will need to know where the PO# was put-away.**

Query for Received:

```
Select hu_ID, Control_number_2
from t_tran_log ttl WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE tran_type = **'151'**
AND ttl.end_tran_date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-02'
```

Query for Put-away:

```
Select hu_ID, Control_number_2, location_ID_2
from t_tran_log ttl WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE tran_type = **'202'**
AND ttl.end_tran_date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-02'
```

thank you!

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimial Reproduceable Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576) That [mcve] should include sample data (preferably with the DDL to produce it), the output you want to obtain from that data, and your effort to write the SQL needed to produce that output.

Comment: Hi, does the Tag is correct. Is it Oracle or SQL Server.

Comment: Do you need any of the info when the tran_type is 151?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, then try this code:

```
Select hu_ID, Control_number_2, location_ID_2
from t_tran_log ttl WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE tran_type = **'202'** OR tran_type = **'151'**
AND ttl.end_tran_date BETWEEN '2019-09-01' and '2019-09-02'
```